# Referencing the output of Parent stack in nested stack - Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc, nested-stack

I am trying to create the nested stack but having trouble as I am new to this and still in learning process. I have created the vpc with 2 private and 2 public subnets. Then attached the internet-facing elb to 2 public subnets. I think I am not referencing it right. Vpc is created but while creating elb there is an error `Output 'VpcID' not found in stack` I think there might be a problem in the syntax as I am changing my previous file to nested stack. I might not be referencing right in the Internet facing elb stack.

Root stack:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  bucketname:
    Type: String
    Description: Path to the bucket
    Default: wahaj-webserver
  bucketpath:
    Type: String
    Description: Path to the bucket
    Default: /nested-stack
Resources:
  Vpcstack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Sub "https://${bucketname}.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com${bucketpath}/vpc1.yml"

  elb:
    DependsOn: Vpcstack
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Sub "https://${bucketname}.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com${bucketpath}/internetfacing-elb.yml"
      Parameters:
        SubnetA: !GetAtt Vpcstack.Outputs.SubnetA
        SubnetB: !GetAtt Vpcstack.Outputs.SubnetB
        VpcID: !GetAtt Vpcstack.Outputs.VpcID
```

Vpc stack:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 11.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      InstanceTenancy: default
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
  VPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  SubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.0.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
  SubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2b
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.1.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
  SubnetC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.2.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
  SubnetD:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2b
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.3.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
  RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  RouteTable2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  InternetRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
  SubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA
  SubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetB
  SubnetCRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable2
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetC

  SubnetDRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable2
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetD
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: "Internet Group"
      GroupDescription: "SSH traffic in, all traffic out."
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: "22"
          ToPort: "22"
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  NAT:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - EIP
          - AllocationId
      SubnetId:
        Ref: SubnetA
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: wahaj-nat
  EIP:
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: VPC
  Route:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId:
        Ref: RouteTable2
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId:
        Ref: NAT
Outputs:
  VpcID:
    Description: VPC id
    Value: !Ref VPC
    Export:
      Name: "VpcID"
  SubnetA:
    Description: public subnet
    Value: !Ref SubnetA
    Export:
      Name: "SubnetA"
  SubnetB:
    Description: public subnet 2
    Value: !Ref SubnetB
    Export:
      Name: "SubnetB"
  SubnetC:
    Description: priavte subnet
    Value: !Ref SubnetC
    Export:
      Name: "SubnetC"
  SubnetD:
    Description: private subnet 2
    Value: !Ref SubnetD
    Export:
      Name: "SubnetD"
```

Internet facing elb:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  wahajelb:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: wahaj-elb
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue: "VpcID"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: For traffic from Internet
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: For traffic from Internet
      GroupDescription: Security Group for demo server

  MyLoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Listeners:
        - LoadBalancerPort: "80"
          InstancePort: "80"
          Protocol: HTTP
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref wahajelb
      LoadBalancerName: wahajelb
      Subnets:
        - Fn::ImportValue: "SubnetA"
        - Fn::ImportValue: "SubnetB"
      HealthCheck:
        Target: HTTP:80/SamplePage.php
        HealthyThreshold: "3"
        UnhealthyThreshold: "5"
        Interval: "30"
        Timeout: "5"
Outputs:
  ec2:
    Description: ec2
    Value: !Ref MyLoadBalancer
    Export:
      Name: "MyLoadBalancer"
  lgsg:
    Description: lg-sg
    Value: !GetAtt wahajelb.GroupId
    Export:
      Name: "lgsg"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Vpc stack has an out out of `vpcID` not `VpcID`.

This must be an exact string match for it to be successfully referenced in your `Root stack`

Update your Vpc stack to the below

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 11.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      InstanceTenancy: default
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
  VPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  SubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.0.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
  SubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2b
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.1.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
  SubnetC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.2.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
  SubnetD:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2b
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.3.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
  RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  RouteTable2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  InternetRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
  SubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA
  SubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetB
  SubnetCRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable2
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetC

  SubnetDRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable2
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetD
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: "Internet Group"
      GroupDescription: "SSH traffic in, all traffic out."
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: "22"
          ToPort: "22"
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  NAT:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - EIP
          - AllocationId
      SubnetId:
        Ref: SubnetA
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: wahaj-nat
  EIP:
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: VPC
  Route:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId:
        Ref: RouteTable2
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId:
        Ref: NAT
Outputs:
  VpcID:
    Description: VPC id
    Value: !Ref VPC
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-VpcID"
  SubnetA:
    Description: public subnet
    Value: !Ref SubnetA
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-SubnetA"
  SubnetB:
    Description: public subnet 2
    Value: !Ref SubnetB
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-SubnetB"
  SubnetC:
    Description: priavte subnet
    Value: !Ref SubnetC
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-SubnetC"
  SubnetD:
    Description: private subnet 2
    Value: !Ref SubnetD
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-SubnetD"
```

Comment: I have made some changes to the code now it shows the following error `Parameter values specified for a template which does not require them.` I have added the changes to the question

Comment: I am trying to pass parameters from root.yml to elb.yml.

Comment: You need to remove the parameters in the Root stack being passed into the `elb` resource